# Trying to retrieve value from a different column on filtered list

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to retrieve a cell value from the same row, but from a different column on a filtered list. I can get a value to return, but for some reason, it doesn't return the value that I need, rather just a random value from the list and then add it to my list, which is located on a different worksheet.. I have copied my code down below. Does anyone mind taking a look?

I am using column K which has all the dates for which the orders are due, and I need to retrieve the order number that is listed in column C, which is listed on the same row. Once the order number is found, it is then added to my list on the Bakery Order worksheet starting with row 2, and in column B

```
            Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' Workbook containing this code.

            Dim cel As Range
            Dim OrderNumberRange As Range
            Dim OrderDateRange As Range
            Dim OrderDate As Date
            Dim Start_Date As Date
            Dim End_Date As Date
            Dim Row As Integer
            Dim Order_Column As Integer
            Dim BakeryOrdersheet As Worksheet
                            
            
            Order_Column = 2
            Row = 2
            Set BakeryOrdersheet = wb.Worksheets("Bakery Order")
            
            BakeryOrdersheet.Activate

            For Each cel In Range("K2:K" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                If ((OrderDate >= Start_Date) And (OrderDate <= End_Date)) Then
                    'This "if" statement states that we have found a value between the deliverable dates
                    'Next let's record the work order associated for this project

                    'Start by establishing the last rows for the work orders and and the deliverables

                     Dim OrderNumberLastRow As Long
                     OrderNumberLastRow = .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                     Dim DeliverableDatelastRow As Long
                     DeliverableDatelastRow = .Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                     'Set the ranges for these values

                      Set OrderNumberRange = .Range("E2:E" & OrderNumberLastRow)
                      Set OrderDateRange = .Range("K2:K" & DeliverableDatelastRow)
                      Dim OrderNumber As String
                     
                     'Assuming that we found a date, that matches the conditions, we need to lookup the order number
                      OrderNumber = Application.Index(OrderNumberRange, Application.Match(cel, OrderDateRange, 0))


                      With BakerySchedule

                        Cells(Row, Order_Column).Value = OrderNumber
                        Row = Row + 1

                      End With
                Else
                End If
```

Comment: `Cells(Row, Order_Column).Value = OrderNumber` has no worksheet reference, nor does your `rows.count` in your last row calcs or the `range()` in your `For each` loop.  Start with those.  Relying on `.Activate` is not a sustainable option, where it lowers performance among many issues.

Comment: Another point to add, if you're just looking to find `.Row` of your `Match`/`Find`, then you can utilize `destWS.Cells(row,order_column).value  = sourceWS.Cells(orderNumber.Row,"C")`.  This saves you from having to invoke an application function (`index`).